# Bold Font for dompdf 0.7.0 beta

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

I'm using DOMPDF ver. 0.7.0 to make a pdf file from HTML, but I have problem when I need to use custom font (arial) with bold style. the bold font won't work after rendering.

here's the CSS style I'm using now:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url(dompdf/font/arial.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'font';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url(dompdf/font/arialbd.ttf);
}
body{
    font-family: 'font';
}
```

and here's dompdf - php code:

```
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('pdf/sptjm.pdf', $pdf)
```

here's the result in HTML:
[image]

and here's the result in PDF:
[image]

the pdf didn't show the bold type, please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the HTML itself look like?

Comment: @BrianS it's solved buddy. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have done it simply with using different font name:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url(dompdf/font/arial.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'font2';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url(dompdf/font/arialbd.ttf);
}
body{
    font-family: 'font';
}
```

so when i need the bold font type, just simply call the other font name 'cuz basically it is different font source.

Comment: I have the same problem. Different font names work. But why the same font name doesn't work? Bug?

Comment: I was looking for this now and instead found that there is a difference between declaring it as "bold" and 700. I was using weight-based declarations for the font-family. I added a bold definition and it worked. Adding this here in case anyone stumbles here and has the same issue.